# Multiple javascript dropdown clones

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to use javaScript clone and remove functions multiple times on a page, but I would like to do it with one script. I have about 20 drop downs that should have the function to be cloned/deleted as part of setup page, these drop downs are created dynamically from PHP and MySQL

The dropdowns and buttons seem to have the correct names and the incremented numbers on the ends line up. However I am not sure how about how to pass those names to the javaScript file below. I'd appreciate any help, let me know if you need anything else.

Index:

```
$add_button        = '#btnAdd[]';
$delete_button     = '#btnDel[]';
$cloned_input      = '.clonedInput[]';
```

cloneMultiple.php

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function() {

    var inputs = 1; 

    $('<?php echo $add_button; ?>').click(function() {
        $('<?php echo $delete_button; ?>:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        var c = $('<?php echo $cloned_input; ?>:first').clone(true);
        $('<?php echo $cloned_input; ?>:last').after(c);
    });

    $('<?php echo $delete_button; ?>').click(function() {
        if (confirm('continue delete?')) {
            --inputs;
            $(this).closest('<?php echo $cloned_input; ?>').remove();
            $('<?php echo $delete_button; ?>').attr('disabled',($('<?php echo $cloned_input; ?>').length  < 2));
        }
    });


});
//]]>  
</script>
```

Here is a sample of the HTML output as requested

```
<div style="float:left; width:33%;"><hr/>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd2" class="add" style="width:180px;" value="Add Air Hammer" />
    <div class="clonedInput2" id="clonedInputed2">Air Hammer
        <label class="input input-right-small">
            <input type="button" class="btnDel delete" id="btnDel2" value="X" disabled="disabled" />
                <select id="AirHammer2" name="AirHammer2" style="width:160px;">
                    <option value="none" selected style="color:gray">None</option>
                </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:33%;"><hr/>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd3" class="add" style="width:180px;" value="Add Boiler" />
    <div class="clonedInput3" id="clonedInputed3">Boiler
        <label class="input input-right-small">
            <input type="button" class="btnDel delete" id="btnDel3" value="X" disabled="disabled"/>
                <select id="Boiler3" name="Boiler3" style="width:160px;">
                    <option value="none" selected style="color:gray">None</option>
                </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
     $getEquipment = "SELECT * FROM rbs_equipment_type WHERE name != 'Truck'";
        $q_Equipment = $conn->prepare($getEquipment);
            $q_Equipment->execute();
                while($rowEquipment = $q_Equipment->fetch())
                    {
                    echo'
                    <div style="float:left; width:33%;"><hr/>
                        <input type="button" id="btnAdd'.$rowEquipment['id'].'" class="add" style="width:180px;" value="Add '.$rowEquipment['name'].'" />
                            <div class="clonedInput'.$rowEquipment['id'].'" id="clonedInputed'.$rowEquipment['id'].'">'.$rowEquipment['name'].'
                                <label class="input input-right-small">
                                    <input type="button" class="btnDel delete" id="btnDel'.$rowEquipment['id'].'" value="X" disabled="disabled" style="width:20px; margin:0px;padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:7px;"/>
                                        <select id="'.$rowEquipment['name'].''.$rowEquipment['id'].'" name="'.$rowEquipment['name'].''.$rowEquipment['id'].'" style="width:160px;">
                                        <option value="none" selected style="color:gray">None</option>';
                                        /*Find Children*/

    $getChildren = "SELECT * FROM rbs_equipment_model WHERE model_type_id = ".$rowEquipment['id'];
        $qChildren = $conn->prepare($getChildren);
            $qChildren -> execute();
                while($rowChildren = $qChildren -> fetch())
                    {
                        echo "<option value='".$rowChildren['model_id']."'>".$rowChildren['model_name']."</option>";
                    }
echo                    '</select>
                    </label>
                </div>
           </div>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: The HTML was useful because you've thrown in a red herring with `$add_button = '#btnAdd[]';`. I'm guessing that's in a loop using different code, because there's no way you'd get `btnAdd3` from setting `$add_button = '#btnAdd[]';` - it would output `#btnAdd[]`. Can you copy the code from your PHP that shows exactly how you're setting those variables. Is the javascript also inside the loop?

Comment: Sorry PopNoodles I was just going to start over, this was looking pretty nasty. But if you've gotter figured that'd be great too

Comment: It will take a few minutes to write out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1ry9h1e3/1/

No IDs required, you just need to add a `.wrapper` class to the first div in the loop

```
<div style="float:left; width:33%;" class="wrapper">
```

Then the jQuery can use that to find the elements it needs to find.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputs = 1; 

    $('.add').click(function() {
        var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.wrapper');
        $wrapper.find('.delete').removeAttr('disabled');
        $wrapper.find('.clonedInput:first')
            .clone(true)
                .appendTo($wrapper)
        ;
    });

    $('.delete').click(function() {
        if (confirm('continue delete?')) {
            --inputs;
            var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.wrapper');
            $wrapper.find('.delete:first').attr('disabled', $wrapper.find('.delete').length < 2);
            $(this).closest('.clonedInput').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well I'm going to stop what I am trying to do, this is a a great solution. Thanks!

Comment: Always assume "there must be an easier way to do this" and you often find it. Perhaps use `input-wrapper` as `wrapper` is too generic in retrospect.

Comment: Yep there usually is, I have a habit of code spiraling out of control and then having to cut back.

Comment: We've all been there.